# Menu of sherlock ActionBar in Fragment not showing icon

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, icons, actionbarsherlock

Anyone could help my with the icon not showing issue in sherlock Actionbar. I want to show the menu like: icon title. However, I try many ways from the answers of the similar question, it still only shows the title in the menu, no icons.

Here is the xml code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.my.tab">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_addphoto"
        android:icon="@drawable/photo_icons"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Photo"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_addvideo"
        android:icon="@drawable/video_icons"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Video"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_addtext"
        android:icon="@drawable/text_icons"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Text"
        />
</menu>
```

Here is the code in the Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_news_feed, null);
    setOverflowShowingAlways();

    dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    setTabsValue();

    return view;

}
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.myprofilesettinfs, menu);
    }
```

Could anyone tell me why? Thank you so much =)

Comment: Can you please try changing the `orderInCategory` value? instead of keeping it constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Sherlock, and won't recommend it.

1. However, I found Google documentation that says you should call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` before `onCreateOptionsMenu` occurs. Webpage @ [onCreateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater)) . Method setHasOptionsMenu can be called in OnCreate().
2. Another, set `android:showAsAction="always"` OR `"ifRoom"`.
3. Perhaps the icon is not formatted correctly. For troubleshooting, try the standard icons starting with **@android:drawable**

Comment: Thank you for reply, I change sherlock to v7, and the color of the EditText become white. The background is white so the text that user entered will not be seen. Do you have any idea about this issue? Thanks

Comment: @Maggie, Do you use android:textColor in the layout? Where is the layout, is it the same one you posted?

Comment: Well, no, above it's like another question. I changed Sherlock to v7, get a text color issue in the editText. And for the icon not show issue, still occur. Yes I have setHasOptionsMenu(true) before onCreateOptionsMenu. I have a menu, but no icon only text.

Comment: I just noticed your setting for showAsAction="never", change it to "always" for testing. I edited my answer and added attempts #1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I Create a new Android Project and rewrite everything. Still have no idea how to fix the problem.

Comment: @Maggie, Did you try my suggestion #3? The idea is to use the standard Google icons just to see if that works at all. If it does not work, then there is a problem with configuration, I think.

Comment: I tried all the suggestions. But none of them worked for me. So I rewrite everything,